# Tcl [exec] process leaves zombie if the process forks and exits

Tags: tcl, exec, zombie-process

I have a case when the Tcl script runs a process, which does `fork()`, leaves the forked process to run, and then the main process exits. You can try it out simply by running any program that forks to background, for example `gvim`, provided that it is configured to run in background after execution: `set res [exec gvim]`.

The main process theoretically exits immediately, the child process runs in background, but somehow the main process hangs up, doesn't exit, stays in zombie state (reports as `<defunct>` in `ps` output).

In my case the process I'm starting prints something, I want that something and I want that the process exit and I state it done. The problem is that if I spawn the process using `open "|gvim" r`, then I cannot also recognize the moment when the process has finished. The `fd` returned by `[open]` never reports `[eof]`, even when the program turns into zombie. When I try to `[read]`, just to read everything that the process might print, it hangs up completely.

What is more interesting, is that occasionally both the main process and the forked process print something and when I'm trying to read it using `[gets]`, I get both. If I close the descriptor too early, then `[close]` throws an exception due to broken pipe. Probably that's why `[read]` never ends.

I need some method to recognize the moment when the **main** process exits, while this process could have spawned another child process, but this child process may be completely detached and I'm not interested what it does. I want something that the main process prints before exitting and the script should continue its work while the process running in background is also running and I'm not interested what happens to it.

I have a control over the sources of the process I'm starting. Yes, I did `signal(SIGCLD, SIG_IGN)` before `fork()` - didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution after a long discussion here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/rtaTOC95NJ0

The below script demonstrates how this problem can be solved:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh 

lassign [chan pipe] input output 
chan configure $input -blocking no -buffering line ;# just for a case :) 

puts "Running $argv..." 
set ret [exec {*}$argv 2>@stderr >@$output] 
puts "Waiting for finished process..." 
set line [gets $input] 
puts "FIRST LINE: $line" 
puts "DONE. PROCESSES:" 
puts [exec ps -ef | grep [lindex $argv 0]] 
puts "EXITING."
```

The only problem that remains is that there's still no possibility to know that the process has exited, however the next `[exec]` (in this particular case probably the `[exec ps...]` command did this) cleans up the zombie (No universal method for that - the best you can do on POSIX systems is `[exec /bin/true]`). In my case it was enough that I get one line that the parent process had to print, after which I can simply "let it go".

Still, it would be nice if `[exec]` can return me somehow the PID of the first process and there's a standard `[wait]` command that can block until the process exits or check its running state (this command is currently available in TclX).

Note that `[chan pipe]` is available only in Tcl 8.6, you can use `[pipe]` from TclX alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

Your daemon can also call `setsid()` and `setpgrp()` to start a new session and to detach from the process group.  But these don't help with your problem either.

You will have to do some process management:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

proc waitpid {pid} {
  set rc [catch {exec -- kill -0 $pid}]
  while { $rc == 0 } {
    set ::waitflag 0
    after 100 [list set ::waitflag 1]
    vwait ::waitflag
    set rc [catch {exec -- kill -0 $pid}]
  }
}

set pid [exec ./t1 &]
waitpid $pid
puts "exit tcl"
exit
```

**Edit: Another unreasonable answer**

If the forked child process closes the open channels, Tcl will not wait on it.

Test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
  int   pid;
  FILE  *o;

  signal (SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
  pid = fork ();
  if (pid == 0) {
    /* should also call setsid() and setpgrp() to daemonize */
    printf ("child\n");
    fclose (stdout);
    fclose (stderr);
    sleep (10);
    o = fopen ("/dev/tty", "w");
    fprintf (o, "child exit\n");
    fclose (o);
  } else {
    printf ("parent\n");
    sleep (2);
  }
  printf ("t1 exit %d\n", pid);
  return 0;
}
```

Test Tcl program:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

puts [exec ./t1]
puts "exit tcl"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tcl clears up zombies from background process calls the *next* time it calls `exec`. Since a zombie really doesn't use much resources (just an entry in the process table; there's nothing else there really) there isn't a particular hurry to clean them up.

---

The problem you were having with the pipeline was that you'd not put it in non-blocking mode. To detect exit of a pipeline, you're best off using a `fileevent` which will fire when *either* there's a byte (or more) to read from the pipe *or* when the other end of the pipe is closed. To distinguish these cases, you have to actually try to read, and that can block if you over-read and you're not in non-blocking mode. However, Tcl makes working with non-blocking mode easy.

```
set pipeline [open |… "r"]
fileevent $pipeline readable [list handlePipeReadable $pipeline]
fconfigure $pipeline -blocking false

proc handlePipeReadable {pipe} {
    if {[gets $pipe line] >= 0} {
        # Managed to actually read a line; stored in $line now
    } elseif {[eof $pipe]} {
        # Pipeline was closed; get exit code, etc.
        if {[catch {close $pipe} msg opt]} {
            set exitinfo [dict get $opt -errorcode]
        } else {
            # Successful termination
            set exitinfo ""
        }
        # Stop the waiting in [vwait], below
        set ::donepipe $pipeline
    } else {
        # Partial read; things will be properly buffered up for now...
    }
}

vwait ::donepipe
```

Be aware that using `gvim` in a pipeline is… rather more complex than usual, as it is an application that users interact with.

---

You might find it easier to run a simple `exec` in a separate thread, provided your version of Tcl is thread-enabled and the `Thread` package is installed. (That ought to be the case if you're using 8.6, but I don't know if that's true.)

```
package require Thread

set runner [thread::create {
    proc run {caller targetVariable args} {
        set res [catch {
            exec {*}$args
        } msg opt]
        set callback [list set $targetVariable [list $res $msg $opt]]
        thread::send -async $caller $callback
    }
    thread::wait
}]

proc runInBackground {completionVariable args} {
    global runner
    thread::send -async $runner [list run [thread::id] $completionVariable {*}$args]
}

runInBackground resultsVar gvim …
# You can do other things at this point

# Wait until the variable is set (by callback); alternatively, use a variable trace    
vwait resultsVar

# Process the results to extract the sense
lassign $resultsVar res msg opt
puts "code: $res"
puts "output: $msg"
puts "status dictionary: $opt"
```

For all that, for an editor like `gvim` I'd *actually* expect it to be run in the foreground (which doesn't require anything like as much complexity) since only one of them can really interact with a particular terminal at once.

Comment: I somehow knew that you'll be the only one to answer reasonably :). Unfortunately, none of your solutions is working: the first hangs up on `gets`, the threaded one on `exec`. This can be easily proven also with `gvim` (I gave it only so that it can be easily tested). I need a solution for: accept socket connections, get a command, run a process in bg, forget it. Another request might kill it, but the process will be recognized by cmdline args. I also don't have to make the process fork itself, I just thought it would be easier. Can do also `exec...&` 'slongs I can exit and keep it running

Comment: I think it would be nice if you get a little bit more interested in this topic. This problem doesn't exist in `bash` - you run a process that forks to background and it's running, the CLI returns. Do the same in Tcl and the `[exec]` command will not return (hangs up forever, with the exited process hanging around as zombie). Does it work so by design, really? Normally zombies are exited CHILD processes that are up to be cleaned up by the parent. Somehow, however, the same CHILD processes that DO NOT fork anything, get exited without any zombies. Can you explain that?

Answer (score 0):

At first you say:

> I need some method to recognize the moment when the main process exits, while this process could have spawned another child process, but this child process may be completely detached and I'm not interested what it does.

later on you say:

> If the forked child process closes the open channels, Tcl will not wait on it.

these are two contradictory statements. One one hand you are only interested in the parent process and on the other whether or not the child has finished even thought you also state you aren't interested in child processes that have detached. Last I heard forking and closing the childs copies of the parents stdin,stdout and stderr is detaching (i.e.daemonizing the child process ).  I wrote this quick program to run the above included simple c program and as expected tcl knows nothing of the child process. I called the compiled version of the program /tmp/compile/chuck. I did not have gvim so I used emacs but as emacs does not generate text I wrap the exec in its own tcl script and exec that. In both cases, the parent process is waited for and eof is detected. When the parent exits the Runner::getData runs and the clean up is evaluated.

---

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /opt/usr8.6.3/bin/tclsh8.6  "$0" ${1+"$@"}

namespace eval  Runner {
    variable close
    variable watch
    variable lastpid ""
    array set close {}
    array set watch {}


    proc run { program { message "" }  } {
        variable watch
        variable close
        variable lastpid
        if { $message ne "" } {
            set fname "/tmp/[lindex $program 0 ]-[pid].tcl" 
            set out [ open $fname "w" ]
            puts $out "#![info nameofexecutable]"
            puts $out " catch { exec $program } err "
            puts $out "puts \"\$err\n$message\""
            close $out
            file attributes $fname -permissions 00777
            set fd [ open "|$fname " "r" ]
            set close([pid $fd]) "file delete -force $fname "
        } else {
            set fd [ open "|$program" "r" ]
            set close([pid $fd]) "puts \"cleanup\""
        } 
        fconfigure $fd -blocking 0 -buffering none
        fileevent $fd  readable [ list Runner::getData [ pid $fd ] $fd ]
    }

    proc getData { pid chan } {
        variable watch
        variable close
        variable lastpid
        set data [read $chan]
        append watch($pid)  "$data"
        if {[eof $chan]} {
            catch { close $chan }
            eval $close($pid) ; # cleanup
            set lastpid $pid
        }
    }
}
Runner::run /tmp/compile/chuck ""
Runner::run emacs   " Emacs complete"

while { 1 } {
    vwait Runner::lastpid
    set p $Runner::lastpid
    catch { exec ps -ef | grep chuck } output
    puts "program with pid $p just  ended" 
    puts "$Runner::watch($p)"
    puts " processes that match chuck "
    puts "$output" 
}
```

---

**Output** :
note I exited out of emacs after the child reported that it was exiting.

> ```
>  [user1@linuxrocks workspace]$ ./test.tcl
>  cleanup
>  program with pid 27667 just  ended
>  child
>  parent
>  t1 exit 27670
>   processes that match chuck  avahi      936     1  0  2016 ? 
>    00:04:35 avahi-daemon: running [linuxrocks.local] admin    27992     1  0
>    19:37 pts/0    00:00:00 /tmp/compile/chuck admin    28006 27988  0
>    19:37 pts/0    00:00:00 grep chuck
>
>  child exit
>  program with pid 27669 just  ended
>
>   Emacs complete
> ```

Comment: Tcl script autogeneration? Well, I'd rather try `[chan pipe]` (or pipe from TclX for <8.6).